# fprintf not working in C program compiled using Make

Tags: c, makefile, printf

I have two files with identical C code. I'm compiling one using Make and one using GCC directly (`gcc NAME.c -o NAME`).

In the GCC-compiled program, all fprintf statements work fine. In the Make-compiled program, only the fprintf statements in the if statements work. The other ones don't print anything. I haven't been able to figure it why.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>                       
#include <stdlib.h>                      
#include <string.h>                      

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000                 

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {       
    fprintf(stdout, "test\n");   
    if (argc != 2) {                     
        fprintf(stderr, "You must have one argument: filename or -h\n");
        return 1;
    }   

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0) {    
        fprintf(stdout, "HELP\n"); /*ADD TEXT HERE*/
    }   
    fprintf(stdout, "got to the end\n"); 
    return 0;                            
}
```

My makefile:

```
COMPILER = gcc
CCFLAGS = -ansi -pedantic -Wall

all: wordstat

debug:
    make DEBUG = TRUE

wordstat: wordstat.o
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -o wordstat wordstat.o
wordstat.o: wordstat.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) wordstat.c

clean:
    rm -f wordstat *.o
```

The GCC one (run with -h) outputs:

```
changed text
HELP
got to the end
```

The Make one outputs:

```
HELP
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `make DEBUG = TRUE` isn't the right syntax; it should be `make DEBUG=TRUE`. But a recursive `make` like that probably isn't the best approach anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax fix. What should I do instead?
(I don't have much of an idea what I'm doing; I'm a complete C/Make newbie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the -c option in the makefile:

```
.
.
.    
wordstat.o: wordstat.c  
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c wordstat.c
                            ↑ - important!
```

Else this line doesn't generate an object file but an executable elf file (a.out), and thus may  lead to unexpected behavior because you recompile that to wordstat ( and it is already compiled).